# multi-thread `select` not return on data ready

Tags: linux, select, linux-kernel, posix

An example C program running on recent Linux version:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *func(void *arg) {
    fd_set rfds;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);
    write(1, "ready\n", 6);
    select(1, &rfds, 0, 0, 0);
    write(1, "ok\n", 3);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t[2];
    pthread_create(&t[0], 0, func, 0);
    pthread_create(&t[1], 0, func, 0);
    write(1, "ready\n", 6);
    char buf[1024];
    read(0, buf, 1024);
    pthread_join(t[0], 0);
    pthread_join(t[1], 0);
    return 0;
}
```

### Test

Type a line of text after you see 3 `ready` (1 from main thread and 2 from other threads).

### Result

There may be 0, 1 or 2 threads return from the `select` call and print `ok`.

### Questions

1. Why didn't all blocked `select` calls get notified when data became available?
2. Why didn't `read` notify all `select` calls blocked on the same fd?
3. If data become available and no thread consumes, will all blocked `select` calls be notified eventually?
4. Which of the above answers would change if `epoll` is used instead of `select`?

---

Replace `select` with `epoll`:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *func(void *arg) {
    int epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = 0;
    epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, &ev);
    struct epoll_event events[1];
    write(1, "ready\n", 6);
    int nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, 1, -1);
    write(1, "ok\n", 3);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t[2];
    pthread_create(&t[0], 0, func, 0);
    pthread_create(&t[1], 0, func, 0);
    write(1, "ready\n", 6);
    char buf[1024];
    read(0, buf, 1024);
    pthread_join(t[0], 0);
    pthread_join(t[1], 0);
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives the same result: There may be 0, 1 or 2 threads return from `epoll_wait` and print `ok` (`EPOLLET` or not).

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "edge-sensitive" and "level-sensitive" events?

Comment: @BenVoigt ET is fired on a change, and LT is fired as long as the condition holds?

Comment: Yup.  This discusses that specifically with respect to `select()` and `epoll()`: https://lwn.net/Articles/25137/

Comment: @BenVoigt But I just tested with `epoll`. `EPOLLET` or not, the number of threads returned from `epoll_wait` varies between 0, 1, 2. Same result as with `select`.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is that: If multiple threads monitor (`select` or `epoll`) on the same fd, then it seems all of them are notified when data is ready. Good. But if one thread reads directly from that fd and consumes the data, then all bets are off: It could be all, some, or none of them get notified.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what is going on is that all the threads wake up, but then inside of `select`, `poll`, or `epoll`, the function doesn't return immediately, it checks status on the fds, and there's a race between this status check and the other thread calling `read` and changing the status.